# Port Forwarding/SSH Tunneling Dilemma

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I am in a situation where I need to forward port 9999 on host3 to my localhost. To make it clearer, here is the path between me and the target

localhost----->{Firewall_1 Here}---->host1------>{Firewall_2 Here}---->host2------->host3

I know that I can use "`root@host2:~# ssh -l root -R 9999:host3:9999 localhost`" which do Reverse ssh tunneling, however, I am keen to know how to implement it using "Local" or "Dynamic" SSH tunneling.

Also as stated, 2 firewalls are separating between networks.Also I have access to all hosts except host3.

localhost can ssh to host1 only by "`ssh firewall_1`" where firewall_1 forwards port 22 to host1 port 22.

In the same way, host1 can only ssh to host2 by "`ssh firewall_2`" where firewall_2 forwards port 22 to host2 port 22.

Comment: Target Isn't much better...

Comment: ok ! no problem !

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it using local port forwarders 
    `"ssh -t -t -L 9999:localhost:9999 firewall_1 ssh -L 9999:host3:9999 firewall_2"`

As for Dynamic forwarding, [this](http://pauldotcom.com/2010/03/ssh-gymnastics-with-proxychain.html) post helped me very much.